# How do you display all the values of one field in a collection?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection `AAA` with the fields name, address, phone_no, id. What is the command that will return all the values of one field?

Example:

AAA

```
{name : a, address : 123, phone_no : 456456, id : 123}
{name : b, address : 345, phone_no : 789789, id : 234}
```

How do I write a command that will return all the values of one field, say `phone_no`? The returned values would be `{456456, 789789}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a projection in the "find" call. For your above example, your call would be:

```
AAA.find({}, {phone_no: 1});
```

The second field is your projection. If you leave it out, it will return everything, otherwise you can specify which fields you want to return.

see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

edit: you also need to explicitly exclude the _id field, so to get just phone_no, you would need to use:

```
AAA.find({}, {phone_no: 1, _id: 0});
```

Comment: If I want to input the field name and use the same function in a dynamic way, what should I use?   

Ex:      


    db.collection.find({}, {<dynamic field variable> : 1})

Comment: Yep, that should work. Just make sure that it's a type String.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want duplicates, you can use [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct):

```
db.AAA.distinct('phone_no')
```

Output:

```
[ 456456, 789789 ]
```